# How can I make math equation automatic in HTML5?

Tags: html, web, logic

```html
<label for="name">Please write your real estate's sqm size</label>
<input type="text" id="sqm" name="sqm" required
       minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10" > 
<label for="name">Please price of real estate</label>
<input type="text" id="price" name="price" required
       minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10" >
```

Basically what I want to achieve is to take the input from the SQM size from the first input and take the price of the real estate values. After taking both values dividing them in this order Price/SQM, I want to get the price per sqm of the real estate automatically, so I can connect it to my backend.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is a descriptive language, you can not do calculations with HTML.
What you need is Javascript code.

```
var sqm = document.getElementById("sqm");
var price = document.getElementById("price")
var ppsm = 0 // price per square meter.
ppsm = price.value / sqm.value // you should add some validation before this line
```